# Trying to get values from Column A using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub iterateThroughAll()
    ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim rowRange As Range
    Dim colRange As Range

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rowRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    'Loop through each row
    For Each rrow In rowRange
        'Find Last column in current row
        LastCol = 1 'wks.Cells(rrow, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set colRange = wks.Range(wks.Cells(rrow, 1), wks.Cells(rrow, LastCol)) <-------------- I get a Run-time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error.
        'Loop through all cells in row up to last col
        For Each cell In colRange
            'Do something to each cell
            Debug.Print (cell.Value)
        Next cell
    Next rrow
    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I get an Application-defined or object-defined error. The code looks okay but not sure why its not working here.

I am trying to get all the used cells in Column A

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` in your code. `ScreenUpdating` is acting as a Boolean variable because you didn't use it properly for one, correct syntax would be `Application.ScreenUpdating`

Comment: `rrow` (not declared) is a range and Cells needs a number so try `wks.Cells(rrow.row, 1)` etc

Comment: @SJR - write the whole line, `rrow.row` should be referred twice.

Comment: Also what is the point of not changing `LastCol`? @Vityata- don't want to spoon-feed! Academic now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub iterateThroughAll()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim rowRange As Range, rrow As Range
    Dim colRange As Range, Cell As Range

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rowRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    'Loop through each row
    For Each rrow In rowRange
        'Find Last column in current row
        LastCol = 1 'wks.Cells(rrow, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set colRange = wks.Range(wks.Cells(rrow.Row, 1), wks.Cells(rrow.Row, LastCol))
        'Loop through all cells in row up to last col
        For Each Cell In colRange
            'Do something to each cell
            Debug.Print (Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
    Next rrow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```